# Generic Method's Parameter Assigned to a Class Property

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have run into a situation where I am curious what a possible solution, or alternative, to this use case might be.

I have a class with a method signature that accepts a generic parameter. So I made the method signature itself generic:

```
/// <summary>
///     Input Widget.
/// </summary>
public sealed class InputWidget {
    /// <summary>
    ///     Widget's Control.
    /// </summary>
    public IList<dynamic> Controls { get; private set; }

    public InputWidget AddControl<TC>(InputControl<TC> control) where TC : BaseControl<TC> {
        this.Controls.Add(control);
        return this;
    }
}
```

If I want to assign that parameter to a class property, for whatever reason, I can't do that unless the the property's type is `object`, or starting with .NET 4, `dynamic`.

Using `dynamic` over `object` saves me the trouble of having to work around casting an `object` back to its generic type when I retrieve each element from the list for further usage. But I am also not too happy with `dynamic` since I get no compile type safety, Intellisense, and it can be fatal at run time if I am not careful.

So why am I not simply declaring my class to be generic? Because I don't want to limit my method to accept an `InputControl` of a specific type. Moreover, I have other methods defined, which I omitted, that require the same approach. If would be boring to define my class with N number of generic types, where N is the number of methods in this case.

So what's the best approach to handle a scenario like this? Am I missing something? Am I thinking incorrectly? Even worse, is my design completely wrong and I need to start reading a beginners book again?

Comment: What you're asking to do is inherently non-type-safe.  What if I call `AddControl<Exception>()`?  You probably want a non-generic base type, covariance, and/or constraints.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @SLaks I had omitted the type constraint in the method signature. I added it again in my example.

Comment: @SLaks Basically, I want to understand what the best approach to a problem like this would be. I thought of using a non-generic base type, and indeed, that's the way I solved it for now. But would you mind providing examples of your other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're actually asking how to store a collection of `InputControl<TC>` where each item in the collection can have a different `TC`.

There are two ways to do that:

- Create a non-generic base class or interface that exposes the functionality you need from the collection, and store that instead.  This would also allow you to make all of your methods non-generic
- Replace `InputControl<TC>` with a contravariant interface, and use a `List<IInputControl<BaseControl>>`.  Using contravariance, you would be able to convert arbitrary `IInputControl<TC>`s to `IInputControl<BaseControl>`.

Comment: While I am not specifically asking how to store a collection of `InputControl<TC>` where each item is a different `TC` - in my mind the scenario can work even if the property is not a collection - your answer seems to be right on. Thanks for your help.